# Spotfire Accordion Text Area - cannot reopen panels after collapsing

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion, spotfire

I am using a text area in Spotfire to make an accordion for my filters so I can free up space. My code below will toggle to open and close the panel, and multiple at a time. However, I can only open and close each panel once and then it does not let me open a panel again until I edit the html and save it.

Also, I am trying to get a minus (-) sign to show up when the panel is opened and turn back into a plus when closed again.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .accordion {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #444;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    .active,
    .accordion:hover {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    .accordion:after {
      content: '\002B';
      color: #777;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .active:after {
      content: "\2796";
    }
    
    .panel {
      padding: 0 18px;
      background-color: white;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button class="accordion" style="font-size:medium" ;><b>Department Roles</b></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      <SpotfireControl id="dca19548a0154f4582d1cc8c033f3ea6" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion" style="font-size:medium" ;><b>Studies with Critical Activities</b></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      <SpotfireControl id="228b526015ad4266946b65cad0a5d2dd" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion" style="font-size:medium" ;><b>Study Status</b></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      <SpotfireControl id="7a331814482e46bfb455f1cb06cdd569" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion" style="font-size:medium" ;><b>Site</b></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      <SpotfireControl id="dec00d7ee27244dc8f803190d2684b94" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion" style="font-size:medium" ;><b>Outsourced</b></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      <SpotfireControl id="44a7a79c5d1a497cb120ffe40b2a91cc" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion" style="font-size:medium" ;><b>Planned Start</b></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      <SpotfireControl id="39f882ba6a8f47a4b4257eff761d93e3" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion" style="font-size:medium" ;><b>Actual Start</b></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      <SpotfireControl id="f4fce188fc424d5cabc040b8eac977dd" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion" style="font-size:medium" ;><b>Study Path</b></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      <SpotfireControl id="c294b790054a4011aadaa89ee7ca36f1" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      });
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The snippet works, so whats the problem?

Comment: It works outside of Spotfire, but in Spotfire I can not reopen my panels once I close them and the + does not change to a - when a panel is opened. I was wondering what in Spotfire would be causing this.

Comment: You may need to force refresh the text area. Does it all work normally if you use Tools > Development > Reload Browser?

Comment: Yes, it does work normally after I reload the browser. I have tried using a meta tag to refresh. But this makes my entire Spotfire application glitch every time (5 seconds) and does not keep the panels open that were opened. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to have add the JavaScript to the Js section of the text area.

Also if html sanitation is on then the  tags would not work either and would have to append using the Js in the text area.

https://datashoptalk.com/unscrambling-spotfire-text-area/